# Delete element with a specific attribute

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

As i said in the title :

I want to delete the whole element when i do not get "preRequisite" in the attribute:

(XML) First Element:

```
  <dependency>
     <dependentAssembly dependencyType="install">
     </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
```

(XML) Second Element:

```
<dependency>
     <dependentAssembly dependencyType="preRequisite">
     </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
```

Current Code:

```
private void Deletepopulates()
    {
        filepath = "C:\Folder\Exaple.exe.manifest"
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(filepath);
        foreach(var nodeToDelete in new List<XmlNode>(doc.SelectNodes(filepath + "[@dependencyType!='preRequisite']").Cast<XmlNode>()))
        {
            if (nodeToDelete != null)
            {
                nodeToDelete.ParentNode.RemoveChild(nodeToDelete);
            }
        doc.Save(filepath);
        }
    }
```

Current it does only delete the Child (dependencyType) but it shall delete the element (dependency), is there a way to delete dependency ?

and at: `new List<XmlNode>(doc.SelectNodes(filepath + "[@dependencyType!=preRequisite").Cast<XmlNode>())`i get an Exception called: `System.Xml.XPath.XPathException`

Hopfully its clear otherwhise i'll edit it in your favor :)

Comment: Your XPath expression can't be processed. Are you missing a closing bracket, `]`?

Comment: Thanks, i corrected both of them but it still shows the same exception :/, can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

Your XPath is invalid in 2 ways:

1. Missing closing bracket `]`.
2. You forgot to put single quotes around `preRequisite`. Actually not having the single quotes around `preRequisite` is valid but it doesn't do what you want it to do. It searches a `preRequisite` child node and compares its value to the `dependencyType` attribute.

The rest of your code looks okay, and I expect it to do what you want once you correct the XPath. It should look like this:

```
filepath + "[@dependencyType!='preRequisite']"
```

**Important:** The `filepath` variable must also be valid XPath of course. Now it looks like it holds a file path, which can never make for valid XPath.

What you want, I guess, is just this:

```
doc.SelectNodes("//dependentAssembly[@dependencyType!='preRequisite']")
```

Comment: So actually i'm searching for a child called preRequisite with the value dependenyType ? ._.

Comment: @Gentle It appears that you're a complete beginner at XPath, I suggest you learn it before asking silly questions. Trying to concatenate a filepath to some XPath expression is nuts, frankly.

Comment: I added the filepath-value... and yes i am a copleatly beginner :/ sorry for asking questions which are in ure eyes silly ...

Comment: @Gentle The filepath should only be used to load the document into the `doc` variable, which you do correctly. Once the document is loaded, if you want to select nodes from that document with XPath, the runtime will know you want to select nodes from that file since you specify `doc.SelectNodes`. There is no need to add the filepath to the XPath.

Comment: @Gentle You're welcome. I hope you didn't take the silly question thing personal.

Comment: No no i know im bad.. its ok :)